# How to pass State as props only once after setting the state inside the Map function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a simple weather app as a beginner project in React. After fetching the api data, I wanted to assign the values I got to my states, and since I couldn't seem to set the state anywhere else, I set the state inside the map function. However, I realized that although this did the job, when I console.log() it, the state is set 7 times. This is a problem because I want to pass that data over as a props to a different component, and it is being passed 7 times. So my question is, is if there is a way to make it so that I can pass the state only AFTER the map function has looped and the setState is not being called anymore.

Here is my App component:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.onHandleSubmit = this.onHandleSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            term:"",
            weather: [],
            description: []
        };
    }

    onHandleSubmit(term){
        this.setState({term: term}, () =>{
            fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${this.state.term}&units=imperial&appid=${KEY}`)
                .then(results => {
                    return results.json();    
                }).then(data => {
                    console.log("Data:",data)
                    const response = data.list.slice(0,7).map((item) => {
                        return(
                            <div key={item.dt}>
                                {this.setState({
                                    weather:[...this.state.weather, item.weather],
                                    description: [...this.state.description, item.main]
                                    },() =>{
                                        console.log("Weather: ", this.state.weather)
                                    })}
                            </div>
                    );  
                });
            });            
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onHandleSubmit}/>
                <div>
                    <WeatherCardList weather={this.state.weather} description={this.state.description}/>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

and this onHandleSubmit function is where I fetch the data from the Api after submitting a term from the search bar. It is also here that I mapped over the data and set my state:

```
const response = data.list.slice(0,7).map((item) => {
                        return(
                            <div key={item.dt}>
                                {this.setState({
                                    weather:[...this.state.weather, item.weather],
                                    description: [...this.state.description, item.main]
                                    },() =>{
                                        console.log("Weather: ", this.state.weather)
                                    })}
                            </div>
                    );  
                });
```

EDIT: Here is my WeatherCardList component

```
const WeatherCardList = (props) =>{
  const weather = props.weather.map(weather => {
      return(
        <WeatherCard key={weather.id}/>

      );
  });  

  return <div>
    {weather}
  </div>
};
```

just to clarify, this.state.weather and this.state.description are also arrays, thus the need for a second map function in the WeatherCardList. I haven't really touched the WeatherCard component yet besides doing the initial set up because I want to first solve this current problem.

Comment: Can you share your weathercardlist component?

Answer (score 0):

Don't render the output when you receive the data. Just call `setState({data})`, which will trigger a new render of your component. Do the map iteration in the render function.

```
.then(results => {
   return results.json();
}).then(data => {
   console.log("Data:",data);
   this.setState({data});
})
```

```
render () {
   const {data} = this.state;

   return(
      <div>
         <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onHandleSubmit}/>
         {
            (!data || !data.list) ? null : (
               data.list.slice(0,7).map(item => (
                  <div key={item.dt}>
                     weather: {item.weather}
                     description: {item.main}
                  </div>
               ))
            )
         }
      </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: When I do it your way, I get an error when the data from the api is getting fetched. Specifically, the "this.setState({data});" part.  I get the  "Objects are not valid as a React child" error.